# Angular material/css input inside Div going running over other div

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-material

```css
.lat-long-divider{
  width:100px;
}
.lat-long-spacer{
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
         <div class="ng-animate-disabled" layout flex>
                            <div layout >
                                <strong translate="LABELS.LAT" class="lat-long-spacer"></strong><strong class="lat-long-spacer">:</strong>
                        <inline-edit class="lat-long-divider"  identifier="'measurement-data'" value="$ctrl.asset" display="$ctrl.asset.latitude" value-name="' Latitude'" on-update="$ctrl.updateLat"></inline-edit>

                            </div>
                            <div layout>
                                <strong translate="LABELS.LONG" class="lat-long-spacer"></strong></strong><strong class="lat-long-spacer">:</strong>
                            <inline-edit class="lat-long-divider" identifier="'measurement-data'" value="$ctrl.asset" display="$ctrl.asset.longitude" value-name="' Longitude'" on-update="$ctrl.updateLong"></inline-edit>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

I am using angular material and layout row method so both latitude and longitude will be on a row, I use some basic css to keep them separate. The problem is, according to api data sometime lat and long data have all decimals or no decimals. Rounding the decimal is not an option by the requirement.  if I use a long space between then when the lat long data have fewer digits a large space between them remains. So how can I dynamically make this happen? Either using CSS or angular material. Basically, if I can contain the data inside each of its parent div or create space dynamically by some flex method

Comment: snippet is not running, can yo make a fiddle ? By the way I think your problem is just word-break css property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.longName {
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
#inline-edit-measurement-data{
  width:100px
 }
```

```html
  <div ng-if="$ctrl.identifier == 'measurement-data' && $ctrl.isEditing" >
        <md-input-container>
            <input type="number" aria-label="inline editor" id="inline-input-box" ng-model="$ctrl.display" ng-blur="$ctrl.focusOut()">
       <md-input-container flex>
            <input id="inline-edit-measurement-data" type="number" aria-label="inline editor" id="inline-input-box" ng-model="$ctrl.display" ng-blur="$ctrl.focusOut()">
         </md-input-container>
     </div>
```

pretty much removed css and gave width to for the inline edit component i had